# Oracle BPEL AQ Adapter Configuration

Tags: bpel

i can enqueue and dequeue the data from the oracle bpel service based on condition defined. Is there any way to stop dequeue based on some condition?  for example:

I have three person name(A , B , C) , which are already in queue. while deueuing those data i have three different AQ adapter configured in BPEL service. if person_name='A', bpel service should dequeue the data. Again if person_name='B', bpel service should dequeue the data....... But if person_name='C', bpel service SHOULD NOT dequeue the data. i m using the "PICK" activity to identify the data through AQ adapter using for dequeue (Lke this:: **TAB.USER_DATA.PERSON_NAME='A'**).

IS THERE ANY WAY TO "STOP DEQUEUING" THE DATA BASED ON CERTAIN CONDITION ?? IN MY CASE THE CONDITION IS (PERSON_NAME='C'). when person name is 'C' AQ adapter should not dequeue the data from "QUEUE TABLE". I AM USING ORACLE DB FOR QUEUE PROCESSING.

Thanks in advance.Every suggestion will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use thread count during the AQ configuration or add the property in your service. 
In the meanwhile you can treat your service as a Single Thread Model Service.
Let me know if this works for you.